What you think is the victim, turns out to be the killer
What's that movie where two people are traveling together. One is a tough guy, the other is meek. At the start, it seems like the tough one is the bad guy, forcing the other to travel with him, not letting him leave. Almost like a kidnapping. But then it turns out that the meek one is actually a serial killer. The tough guy knows that.
I vaguely remember a scene where the meek one tries to escape while the tough guy is in the other room.
As if the meek guy has an urge to kill again, but is trying to resist it. The tough guy keeps pushing him though.
I my mind, this was set in an american town with hot weather. Almost like a western vibe, but in modern times. My brain could be making up false memories though.

kindly provide as many information available , year of release or any other minor plots

Was there anything else you remember like was there a kid with them or was it a dessert

Well, it was definitely before 2010, but it may 90's or even 80's.

I saw it on tv. I don't remember there being a kid with them. I think killings were done with knives or axes rather than guns. I'll try my best to remember more.

In the film "The Nature of the Beast" 1995, with Eric Roberts and Lance Henriksen, there is a plot that revolves around a seemingly meek fellow and an outwardly tough guy. Lance plays the older seemingly meeker fellow, while Eric plays a cool tough guy type. 
Set among the back drops of outback highways and road side diners in warm weather with a modern western style to it.
Adrian (Eric Roberts) comes across Jack (Lance Henrikson) and basically kind of semi kidnaps / wont leave Jack.
At one stage Jack tries to take off to get away from Adrian in a hotel setting where they are in separate rooms.
Through out the movie there is mention of a killer, he likes to use an axe / hatchet to do his killings. He is not revealed till well into the movie. 
* Spoiler below *
The twist is the seemingly meek Jack is actually the killer mentioned through the movie.



